# Determine the equation of the line

Tags: calculus

Determine the equation of the line AB

Line AB is a tangent to $2x^2 - 7x$

Line PD is perpendicular to AB

PD is represented by the equation $y = -x + 2$

To get the point of contact between the two lines, 
my math teacher said that it will be $f'(x) = 4x - 7 = -1$

Why is $f'(x) = 4x - 7 = -1$?
Why will it not be $4x - 7 = 1$?
Since:
AB is a tangent and gradient is $1$
PD is perpendicular to AB and PD  gradient is $-1$

Comment: The question looks quite clear to me with a clear answer. Of two formulas for $x$ at the point of tangency, at most one can be correct; we are asked which is the correct one, and it is the student's formula. (Also, the OP clearly did all the work we could reasonably require before asking this!)

Answer (score 2):

Slope of PD =-1. Slope of AB is +1 . Your last equation is quite correct. After finding x, find the y.

Answer (score 1):

Coefficient of x in the equation of line PD is $-1$. Negative reciprocal of that is $1$. So, your teacher is sadly wrong :/ since this tells us that $4x-7=1$